# Screen location of NSToolbarItem

Tags: cocoa, tooltip

How can I get the on-screen location of a button in a toolbar?  That is getting the rectangle frame of an `NSToolbarItem`?  The `[NSToolbarItem view]` method seems to always return `nil` whenever the toolbar item is only a simple action button and thus I couldn't use the normal `NSView` methods to pinpoint the toolbar button's on-screen position.

**Background**

I'm trying to use Matt Gemmell's [`MAAttachedWindow`](http://mattgemmell.com/2007/10/03/maattachedwindow-nswindow-subclass) component to point to a specific toolbar button.  The component requires an `NSPoint` object to "point" the user to a location on the screen.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I happened to have the same kind of problem. Although I wouldn't say I solved it, I found a way that at least works for my scenario...
In my ToolbarItem action I fetch the current mouse location - it proved to be sufficient in this case. An example implementation might look like this:

```
- (IBAction)showOverlay:(id)sender {
    NSPoint clickedPoint = [self.window mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream];
    self.overlayController = [[MyOverlayController alloc] initAtPoint:clickedPoint];
}
```

Comment: Hi Tobidobi,

From the looks of it your solution is applicable when the user actually clicks the button, isn't it?

What if the problem is to put a "click here" signpost?  That is the user haven't clicked on the toolbar button.

Thanks

Comment: That won't work if the user uses a keyboard shortcut to show the popup... in that case, the popup should still be pointing to the toolbar item.